# How to build a program with Make using different build configurations?

Tags: makefile

yesterday I wrote a Makefile to build a Programm which works fine.
Now, I try to build different build configurations.

What is the recommended way to build different configurations which differ in the list of source files and output paths?

I tried to use target specific variables...

> ## Executables of the compiler toolchain.
>
> COMPILER := ccrl
>   LINKER := rlink
>   ASSEMBLER := asrl
>
> DEVICE_FILE := DR5F100LL.DVF
>
> ## Compiler flags used to generate *.d files.
>
> DFLAGS := \
>       -MM \
>       -MP \
>       -cpu=S2 \
>       -dev="$(DEVICE_FILE)" \
>       -no_warning_num=11179,11180 \
>       -g \
>       -Onothing
>
> ## Compiler flags used to generate *.obj files from c source files.
>
> CFLAGS := \
>       -cpu=S2 \
>       -c \
>       -dev="$(DEVICE_FILE)" \
>       -no_warning_num=11179,11180 \
>       -g \
>       -Onothing
>
> ## Compiler flags used to generate *.obj files from assembler files.
>
> ASMFLAGS := $(CFLAGS)
>
> ## Linker flags
>
> LDFLAGS := \
>       -library="${COMPILER_PATH}/lib/rl78cm4s.lib" \
>       -library="${COMPILER_PATH}/lib/rl78cm4r.lib" \
>       -library="./FFT_Library/libfft_rl78g13.lib" \
>       -nooptimize \
>       -entry=_start \
>       -security_id=00000000000000000000 \
>       -ocdbg=04 \
>       -user_opt_byte=EEFFE9 \
>       -debug \
>       -nocompress \
>       -memory=high \
>       -vectn=2=ffff \
>       -rom=.data=.dataR \
>       -rom=.sdata=.sdataR \
>       -nomessage \
>       -device="$(DEVICE_FILE)" \
>       -nologo \
>
> > -start=.const,.text,.RLIB,.SLIB,.textf,.constf,.data,.sdata/03000,.dataR,.bss/0F7F00,.sdataR,.sbss/0FFE20
>
> ## Include directories
>
> C_INCS := \
>       -I${COMPILER_PATH}/inc \
>       ...
>
> ## C source files used build the program.
>
> C_SRCS_FFT_TEST := \
>       CodeGenerator/r_cg_cgc.c \
>       ...
>
> C_SRCS_HISTORY_TEST := \
>       CodeGenerator/r_cg_cgc.c \
>       ...
>
> C_SRCS_IOLINK_TEST := \
>       CodeGenerator/r_cg_cgc.c \
>       ...
>
> ## Assembler files used to build the program.
>
> ASM_SRCS := \
>       ...
>
> ## Root directories of the build results.
>
> OUT_ROOT_DIR := build
>   PUBLISH_ROOT_DIR := publish
>
> .SECONDEXPANSION:
>
> ## Name of the build configuration.
>
> BUILD_CONFIG = Unknown
>
> OUT_DIR =$(OUT_ROOT_DIR)/$(BUILD_CONFIG)
>   PUB_DIR =$(PUBLISH_ROOT_DIR)/$(BUILD_CONFIG)
>
> ## Determine file paths of generated files.
>
> OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,$(OUT_DIR)/%.obj,$(C_SRCS))
>   OBJS += $(patsubst %.asm,$(OUT_DIR)/%.obj,$(ASM_SRCS))
>   DEPS = $(OBJS:.obj=.d)
>
> ## Filenames of the output files.
>
> OUT_FILE = $(PUB_DIR)/MyFile.abs
>   MAP_FILE = $(OUT_DIR)/MyFile.map
>
> .PHONY: build-definitions
>   build-definitions: fft-test history-test iolink-test
>
> fft-test: BUILD_CONFIG=FFT_Test
>   fft-test: C_SRCS=$(C_SRCS_FFT_TEST)
>   .PHONY: fft-test
>   fft-test: $$(OUT_FILE)
>
> history-test: BUILD_CONFIG=History_Test
>   history-test: C_SRCS=$(C_SRCS_HISTORY_TEST)
>   .PHONY: history-test
>   history-test:
>     @echo -e "Building $(BUILD_CONFIG)."
>
> iolink-test: BUILD_CONFIG=IOLink_Test
>   iolink-test: C_SRCS=$(C_SRCS_IOLINK_TEST)
>   .PHONY: iolink-test
>   iolink-test:
>     @echo -e "Building $(BUILD_CONFIG)."
>
> .PHONY: all
>   all: pre-build $(OUT_FILE) post-build
>
> .PHONY: pre-build
>   pre-build: 
>     @echo -e "Run pre-build target."
>
> .PHONE: post-build
>   post-build:
>     @echo -e "Run post-build target."
>
> .PHONY: clean
>   clean:
>     @echo -e "Run clean target."
>     @rm -f -v $(OUT_DIR)/LinkerSubCommand.tmp
>     @rm -f -v $(OBJS)
>     @rm -f -v $(DEPS)
>     @rm -f -v $(OUT_FILE)
>     @rm -f -v $(MAP_FILE)
>
> ## How to build the dependency file from a c source file.
>
> $(OUT_DIR)/%.d : %.c
>     @echo 'Building d file: $<'
>     @mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
>     $(COMPILER) $(DFLAGS) $(C_INCS) -o "$(@:%.obj=%.d)" -MT="$@" -MT="$(@:%.obj=%.d)" "$<"
>
> ## How to build the dependency file from an asm file.
>
> $(OUT_DIR)/%.d : %.asm
>     @echo 'Building d file: $<'
>     @mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
>     $(COMPILER) $(DFLAGS) $(C_INCS) -o "$(@:%.obj=%.d)" -MT="$@" -MT="$(@:%.obj=%.d)" "$<"
>
> ## How to build the object file from a c source file.
>
> $(OUT_DIR)/%.obj : %.c
>     @echo 'Building obj file: $<'
>     @mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
>     $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(C_INCS) -o "$@" "$<"
>     @echo -e $(@:%=-input=\"%\") >> $(OUT_DIR)/LinkerSubCommand.tmp
>
> ## How to build the object file from an asm file.
>
> $(OUT_DIR)/%.obj : %.asm
>     @echo 'Building asm file: $<'
>     @mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
>     $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(C_INCS) -o "$@" "$<"
>     @echo -e $(@:%=-input=\"%\") >> $$(OUT_DIR)/LinkerSubCommand.tmp
>
> #
>   $(OBJ): %.obj: %.c $(DEPS)
>
> ## How to build the output file from all object files.
>
> %.abs : $(OBJS)
>     @echo -e "Building $(BUILD_CONFIG)."
>     @echo -e "The output directory is $(OUT_DIR)."
>     @echo -e "The publish directory is $(PUB_DIR)."
>     @echo -e "The source files are $(C_SRCS)."
>     @echo -e "The assembler files are $(ASM_SRCS)."
>     @echo -e "The generated object files are $(OBJS)."
>     @echo -e "Building output file is $@."
>     @mkdir -p "$(PUB_DIR)" 
>     @mkdir -p "$(OUT_DIR)" 
>     $(LINKER) $(LDFLAGS) -subcommand="$(OUT_DIR)/LinkerSubCommand.tmp" -list="$(MAP_FILE)" -output="$(OUT_FILE)"

I know that I should use private as scope of the target specific variables but than I have to download/compile a newer make Version...

I would like to know the recommended way to build such configurations.
Maybe someone can provide a simple (and complete) example?

Thanks a lot!
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(config), debug)
    CFLAGS := -DDEBUG -g
    OUT_PATH := ./build/debug/
else ifeq ($(config), light_debug)
    CFLAGS := -g
    OUT_PATH := ./build/light_debug/
else #release config by default
    OUT_PATH := ./build/release
endif

#...
```

Then `make` invokation is like this:

```
make confg=debug
```

or

```
make config=light_debug
```

or

```
make config=release
```

Comment: Thank you but in this case I can not call make debug light_debug release. Is there any solution based on targets?

Comment: you can call `make config=debug && make config=release`. Anyway, the value of `make debug release` does not look major.